# iTunes 12.2 xml file is not present after upgrading my OS X to 10.10.4 and iTunes to 12.2

Tags: itunes

After upgrading my Mac OSX to 10.10.4 and iTunes to 12.2, the iTunes music library XML file is not created under /users/music/iTunes folder.
I tried creating the xml file manually, but it gets deleted after 5-10 seconds automatically.
Any workaround to resolve this problem?

Comment: it probably moved to another place. try searching for it with "mdfind iTunes Music Library.xml" in your terminal app.

Comment: Tried that as well, but did not work. I could not find any other iTunes music library.xml file in my machine. Also, if I create it manually by doing library export, it gets removed automatically after around 10 seconds.

Comment: it would help if you disclose what you have tried already.

Comment: I mean, along with whatever I tried already as mentioned in the description, I tried what you have suggested -> that also did not solve the problem. Thanks for asking me to be more precise.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but might be worth a try… http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194246/after-upgrading-itunes-all-my-media-has-disappeared

Answer (score 3):

iTunes 12.2 definitely still generates an `iTunes Music Library.xml` file. From my machine, running 10.10.4 and iTunes 12.2:

```
~/Music/iTunes$ ls -l "iTunes Music Library.xml"
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mj  staff  109833070 Jul  2 14:20 iTunes Music Library.xml
```

That date and time stamp are the date and time I last exited iTunes.

That said, you can recreate the XML file. Apple has document [HT201561](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201561) that describes the process as well as the purpose of the XML file and when it gets recreated, but note all of the warnings in that document.

**Update:** The generation of the XML is now optional in iTunes 12.2 - check *Preferences* > *Advanced* and set the option *Share iTunes Library XML with other applications*

Comment: See also [HT201610](http://web.archive.org/web/20160104232229/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201610) that explains the switch to optional.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they don't save the xml file by default anymore. You have to turn it on in iTunes' preferences.