# After upgrading iTunes all my media has disappeared

Tags: itunes, macos

I have just upgraded to iTunes 12.2 on OSX Yosemite. Initially iTunes refused to open at all so I rebooted.  Now I see that I have no media in my library (other than items bought from iTunes directly).

I have tried holding down the option key when opening iTunes so that I can choose my library, but that seems to make no difference.  I suspect it has flattened by .ITL file during the upgrade.

I thought the days of iTunes losing all of your music were over?  Apparently not!

What is the best way to fix this?  Do I have to manually re-add all of my music and movie files again?

Comment: Strangely if I use the search feature in iTunes then I see my albums, but I am unable to click on them!  It is as if the main view of iTunes is filtered to only show things I bought on iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of fixed it. I signed out of iTunes, then my music appeared! It seems to remain in place when I signed back in, so maybe, all is good